# Need a total for type of events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a company that has held a certain amount of events that equal 'social'. I need a total of these events based on the COMPANY, but am throwing an error when attempting to SUM or CONVERT or CAST on the EVENT_TYPE column. I've been staring at the issue for too long and thought a fresh set of eyes and brains could help me find the obvious. Here's the Code:

```
SELECT     Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE,
           Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE,
           Name.COMPANY,
           COUNT(CE_EVENT_TYPE) AS Expr1

FROM       Demo_Chapter_Events
INNER JOIN Name
ON         Demo_Chapter_Events.ID = Name.ID
WHERE      (Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'social')
AND        (Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE 
              BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) 
              AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))

GROUP BY Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE,
         Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE,
         Name.COMPANY

ORDER BY Name.COMPANY
```

Sample output -

```
CE_EVENT_TYPE                            CE_EVENT_DATE           COMPANY                                                                          Expr1
---------------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
SOCIAL                                   2015-09-17 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-08 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-29 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-19 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-12-03 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-05 00:00:00.000 Alpha Alpha Chapter                                                              6
SOCIAL                                   2015-09-24 00:00:00.000 Alpha Beta Chapter                                                               3
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-13 00:00:00.000 Alpha Beta Chapter                                                               3
SOCIAL                                   2015-12-05 00:00:00.000 Alpha Beta Chapter                                                               3
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-14 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chapter                                                                    1
SOCIAL                                   2015-09-19 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-16 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-21 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-22 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-24 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-10-30 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-11-12 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
SOCIAL                                   2015-09-18 00:00:00.000 Alpha Chi Chapter                                                                16
```

Comment: It's tagged for both. my apologies. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It's SQL to actually answer your question.

Comment: the problem is I dont see `SUM` or `CONVERT` in your query. First we need the query causing the error and the exact error message. Then we need to know your db schema to know what type is your field. and last show us some sample data.

Comment: The EVENT_TYPE column is the CE_EVENT_TYPE column? And it contains words like 'social'? And you want a SUM of such words? Or you want to cast the word? To what data type? That sounds a bit confused :-)

Comment: CE_EVENT_TYPE is the column containing the word 'social'. I need a SUM total of occurrences of the CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'social' attributed to the Name.COMPANY column so that the output is a column that represents a total INT amount for each Name.Company. CAST, SUM and CONVERT pitch 'unable to convert varchar 'social' to INT. Current results list recurring Name.Company, the CE_EVENT_TYPE and a single digit representing the CE_EVENT_TYPE as follows: [link]http://imgur.com/LkORY1e

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: Is there some reason it isn't just COUNT(*) ?   And if you don't want the COUNT to be grouped by date, you can do it in a subquery.

Comment: 'unable to convert varchar 'social' to INT'

Comment: COUNT is in there in the SELECT statement, but it is returning only one digit per occurrence. Here's a screenshot - [link]http://imgur.com/LkORY1e

Comment: Looks like the results in your image are from a query that wasn't grouped properly, is all.

Comment: MS Visual Studio pitches a fit when I try to only GROUP BY one column. It tells me that the rest of my columns are invalid because they are not part of the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try to just group by one column in the GROUP BY - Column 'Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

The way your question is currently worded, here is how I would solve it:

```
SELECT     d1.CE_EVENT_TYPE,
           d1.CE_EVENT_DATE,
           n1.COMPANY,
           (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Demo_Chapter_Events d2
            INNER JOIN Name n2
             ON d2.ID = n2.ID
            WHERE n2.Company=n1.Company
            AND d2.CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'social'
            AND (d2.CE_EVENT_DATE 
              BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) 
              AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
           ) AS Expr1

FROM       Demo_Chapter_Events d1
INNER JOIN Name n1
ON         d1.ID = n1.ID
WHERE      (d1.CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'social')
AND        (d1.CE_EVENT_DATE 
              BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) 
              AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))

GROUP BY d1.CE_EVENT_TYPE,
         d1.CE_EVENT_DATE,
         n1.COMPANY

ORDER BY Name.COMPANY
```

EDIT:

I have edited the code above to not require the group by d1.ID, and to more correctly get the count based on the Company column from the Name table.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I was struggling with the subquery concept a little bit. I am new to forums in this regard so I appreciate everyone's patience. Unfortunately I get this error message - Column 'Demo_Chapter_Events.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You were not selecting ID in the query in your question.   If you need to add it to the SELECT list, you need to also add it to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Apologies, I added the 'Demo_Chapter_Events.ID' to the GROUP_BY and it seems to be returning now. Thank you.

Comment: One final thing as this code works beautifully, how do I get this to display just the name and the totals without the repeating elements? See screenshot [link]http://imgur.com/YvEuyfy

Comment: I guess that would be a good time to apply DISTINCT, wouldn't it. (duh) Thank you, all!

Comment: Currently the query is running at 95%. The remaining 5% is that there are somehow some residual rows that even after using DISTINCT will not go away. Any help is appreciated. I don't have the DISTINCT in the code currently. It's so close.

Here is a link to what the output currently looks like. Rows 4,5, and 7 are repeating the same information. etc. [http://imgur.com/LIqIiEe][1]

Comment: What are you grouping by in the query that produces the results in the image?   Must be more than just Chapter, EventType and MemberType.

Comment: I think there are some other filters that ended up being required Here is the GROUP BY - 
"GROUP BY d1.CE_EVENT_TYPE, d1.CE_EVENT_DATE, Name_1.COMPANY, d1.ID, Name_1.MEMBER_TYPE, Name_1.STATUS"

Comment: Even reverting back to your original code, it's rendering duplicates. I tried DISTINCT and still flummoxed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That last image can't be what my query renders, because it's missing EventType and EventDate and has Chapter instead of Company.   I think that you are showing us a simplified version of your real query, and then trying to modify your real query based on my answer, without correctly applying the principles involved.   In order to help, we're going to have to see your real query.

Comment: Aw crap...yes, I uploaded an incorrect photo. Just re-copied and pasted your code and this is the render. Sorry bout that! 
http://imgur.com/IarNo4P

Comment: I just changed the header title from COMPANY to CHAPTER because eventually that's how the client will want it displayed, but here is my direct copy/paste of the code you posted in to MS Visual Studio with the ID added to group by as it was pitching a fit earlier, which you already commented upon. - http://imgur.com/CkHG0VH

Comment: Ok, I have edited my code to eliminate the need to include `ID` in the GROUP BY clause.   This should not have any duplicates.

Comment: I think it must be the way that MS Visual Studio is interpreting the code, because it is still not returning on one row. [link]http://imgur.com/lsJhWFw

Thanks for all your help. I will continue to study up on what you have submitted and see if there's a work around.

Comment: Can't you try it in SSMS?

Comment: I get an error message in SSMS - Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Demo_Chapter_Events'.

Comment: Apologies - I ran it through the wrong DB. New at my position and still learning where all of my connections go. This is the actual error message - Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The multi-part identifier "Name.COMPANY" could not be bound.

Comment: Ah.   In the ORDER BY, please change `Name.COMPANY` to `n1.COMPANY`.   I missed that.